# Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash: Aliases not working (: command not found)

Tags: bash, bash-alias, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

I started the Ubuntu bash on Windows that was shipped with the Anniversary Update 1607. This bash sources the `.bashrc` file located at `/home/phil` which is the home directory of the Unix user, not the Windows user (this would be `/mnt/c/Users/Philipp`). In this file is among other things the following piece of code:

```
if [ -f .bash_aliases ]; then
    . .bash_aliases
fi
```

Since I already have a aliases file in my Windows home directory, I replaced that piece with:

```
if [ -f /mnt/c/Users/Philipp/.aliases_win ]; then
     . /mnt/c/Users/Philipp/.aliases_win
fi
```

Which when restarting bash or sourcing directly with `source /mnt/c/Users/Philipp/.aliases_win` gives:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

So I removed as many aliases until these error messages disappeared, leaving only these aliases in the file:

(For reference, the complete file looks like this: https://github.com/kleinfreund/dotfiles/blob/master/win/bash/.aliases)

```
# Quickly navigate up the *great hollow*
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ....='cd ../../..'
alias .....='cd ../../../..'
```

But upon using:

```
phil@RAUMSTATION:~$ ..
: File or directory not found
```

However when I do `alias ..='cd ..'` directly from within bash, it works fine.

I'm now utterly confused. What am I doing wrong? The aliases file works fine on my Ubuntu installation and also with things like Git Bash.

**Edit:** Putting my aliases into `/home/phil/.bashrc` works, not so much when sourcing the file from my Windows users’ home directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the line endings of `/mnt/c/Users/Philipp/.aliases_win` from windows format (CRLF) to unix format (LF). You can do this with sed (this will overwrite the file):

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' /mnt/c/Users/Philipp/.aliases_win
```

Explanation:

The reason bash says `: command not found` is because it interprets the carriage return on the "blank" lines in your windows-formatted file as the name of a command. You can test this for yourself in the bash shell by typing CTRL-V, CTRL-M and then hitting enter (CTRL-M or ^M corresponds to a carriage return, see `man console_codes`).

Once you removed all the blank lines, you were left with just a few alias commands, which gave you `: File or directory not found` after executing the aliases because the carriage return on the end of the alias lines was actually added into the alias. For example, the line `alias ..='cd ..'<CR><LF>` made `..` an alias for `cd ..<CR>`, which does not go to the parent folder `..` but instead tries to change to the directory with the name `..<CR>`. The error message when running this alias doesn't start with the typical `bash: cd: foldername` because echoing the carriage return in the folder name causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line; try something like `echo aaaa<CR>bb` to see this more clearly.